# Ubuntu 11.04 does not recognize external projector

Tags: drivers

I have tried to use an external projector at work, which works alright with the same laptop on windows.
As I am not very skilled in computers, so I am just kind of freaking out. could you give me some help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

I experience those issues too. For me, bringing up the "Monitor Preferences" dialog seems to trigger a "scan" if a projector or external monitor is connected, and fixes the problem in most cases. Unfortunately this does not work for each and every case, but I could not find any better solution yet.